# string to date not working (php & MySQL

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a column in MySQL where date is a string (d/m/Y).
when I try to get this table ordered by date I get an internal server error and nothing happens:

```
$pdo->prepare('SELECT IdOrder,Name,Lname,Phone,Date FROM ordenes WHERE Lname LIKE ? ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%d/%m/%Y') DESC LIMIT 50');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this works

```
$pdo->prepare("SELECT IdOrder,Name,Lname,Phone,Date FROM ordenes WHERE Lname LIKE ? ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%d/%m/%Y') DESC LIMIT 50");
```

You are using single quotes both in query and date format so you get PHP error.
Another way is using backslashs:

```
$pdo->prepare('SELECT IdOrder,Name,Lname,Phone,Date FROM ordenes WHERE Lname LIKE ? ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(Date, \'%d/%m/%Y\') DESC LIMIT 50');
```

Comment: LOL such a noob, It works!, should I delete this post?